# Spark SQL mismatched input expecting {<EOF>, ';'}

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the error "Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'BirthYear' expecting {, ';'}(line 9, pos 13)". However, the case statement is not the End of File?

Query:

```
select
    TransactionID as txn_id,
    Message as msg_txt,
    Source as src_sys,
    Firstname as indv_frst_nm,
    Middlename as indv_mdl_nm,
    Lastname as indv_last_nm,
    CASE
        WHEN BirthYear IS NULL OR BirthMonth IS NULL OR BirthDay IS NULL THEN ''
        WHEN TRYCAST(CONCAT(CAST(BirthYear AS string), '-', CAST(BirthMonth AS string), '-', CAST(BirthDay AS string) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')) IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(TRYCAST(CONCAT(CAST(BirthMonth AS string), '-', CAST(BirthMonth AS string), '-', CAST(BirthDay AS string) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS string)
        ELSE '9999-12-31'
    END AS indv_brth_dt,
    DecisionCode as dcsn_cd,
    tddate as td_dt,
    RUN_ID as run_id,
    AuthorizedRepAddressCounty as auth_rep_verf_ad_cnty_nm,
    CASE
        WHEN TRYCAST(CONCAT(CAST(AuthorizedRepYearOfBirth AS string), '-', CAST(AuthorizedRepMonthOfBirth AS string), '-', CAST(AuthorizedRepDayOfBirth AS string) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')) IS NOT NULL THEN
            CAST(TRYCAST(CONCAT(CAST(AuthorizedRepYearOfBirth AS string), '-', CAST(AuthorizedRepMonthOfBirth AS string), '-', CAST(AuthorizedRepDayOfBirth AS string) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS string)
        ELSE
            NULL
    END AS auth_rep_verf_brth_dt
from table_name;
```

Comment: The issue could be related to using `TRYCAST` ? is this function available in spark?

Comment: So this is in a SQL file and I'm applying a transformation on a dataframe by calling this file. But I don't know I will look into it.